# Rails 4: Unpermitted parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, data-uri

I have a model Picture where I take a photo with webcam and save it. I upload the images with carrierwave, and generate the image with the gem [carrrierwave-data-uri](https://github.com/timsly/carrierwave-data-uri) The image is sent by ajax

**the function on my PicturesController.rb is:**

```
def upload_image
    photo = params[:picture][:photo]   
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    @picture.user_id = current_user.id 
    @picture.photo = photo
    @picture.save
  end


  private
    def set_picture
      @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    end

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:photo, :comment, :user_id )
    end
end
```

**My Ajax**

```
function save_photo() {
  Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/pictures/upload',
      async: true,
      data: { picture: {photo: data_uri} }
    })

    .done(function () {
      console.log(photo);
    });

    Webcam.reset();

  } );
}
```

When I send the image, it is registered on database, but not the image. I getting the console error:

Unpermitted parameter: image

But if I add the parameter **:image** on my strong parameters, I get the **Completed 500 Internal Server Error**

The data uri is printed on my console, but I can't put it in a **image** variable

Thanks by help!

Comment: `data_uri = params[:image]`. Try `params[:picture][:image]`. Also the unpermitted parameter errors occurs because image is not there in strong params. I do not know whether you have an **image attribute** for the **picture** model. That must be the reason for `internal server error`.

Comment: Thanks, but same error. I did: data: { picture: {photo: data_uri} } but the photo value is coming empty ["photo", nil]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 500 Internal Server Error when  permitting `image` because you don't have an `image` attribute in the model. You have `photo` instead, so you should use it as the parameter to send `data_uri` in the `ajax` method.

Change `image` in the AJAX call to `photo`:

```
data: { picture: { photo: data_uri } }
```

Also make change in your controller method like this:

```
def upload_image 
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    @picture.user_id = current_user.id 
    @picture.save
end
```

Comment: When I did that, i get no parametter error, but the photo value is coming empty in console: [["photo", nil]

Comment: can you debug in your `ajax` method to see if  `data_uri` has value while making the request?

Comment: Yes, I did that. The value is there. I debug on rails console too, with puts. But when I do @picture.photo = photo, the value remains empty

Comment: did you also make changes in controller method?

Comment: It works, not getting the error anymore, but when I do @picture.photo = photo, the photo value is coming empty ["photo", nil]

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but I still have to @picture.photo = photo to save the image too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120736/discussion-between-titan-and-fernando-aureliano).